# Overriding jQuery.mobile-1.1.0.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, overriding, appendto

I'm having a hard time with overriding a core jQuerymobile function. 
Here's the link to JQM library Im using: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js

I changed line 5873

```
.appendTo( wrapper )
```

to following code:

```
.appendTo( *My own code*  )
```

But I'm aware that changing the code directly inside JQM library isnt the best way to achieve what I need. So I would like to make an override in a custom js file.
How would I do it, in order to override the least of the JQM lib code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is found within a delegated event handler, so you could overwrite that event handler with your own from an external file.

Lines 5788 to 5884 (with most of the code redacted):

```
$( document ).delegate( ":jqmData(role='listview')", "listviewcreate", function() {
    ...
        .appendTo( wrapper )
    ...
});
```

So in your external JS code you can remove this event handler and attach your own:

```
$(document).undelegate(":jqmData(role='listview')", "listviewcreate").delegate(":jqmData(role='listview')", "listviewcreate", function () {
    //your version of the above code here
});
```

Note that `.delegate()` and `.undelegate()` should be replaced with `.on()`/`.off()` if you're using jQuery 1.7 or newer.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked perfectly. Although I'm still curious whether there is a shorter way how to do it, without copying the whole 5788->5884 block of code into my custom script as I want to alter only one line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after jquery initialized

```
jQuery.fn.extend({append: function() { **Your code here** } });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include a custom JavaScript file after you load jQuery, but before you bring in jQuery mobile.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>  
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```